# iOS Program Questions...Which Site?

Tags: discussion, asking-questions

I've just applied to the iOS program and have some general questions that I cannot find covered on the Apple site.  I'd like to ask them on a StackExchange site, but I'm confused as to whether they belong on the StackOverflow, Programmers, or Apple site.  I've seen iOS questions migrated from StackOverflow and then closed on Apple, so clearly I'm not the only one confused.

What's the best practice?

---

**UPDATE:**

As requested, here is the example that I saw:

- https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/8237/ios-apple-developer-organization-profile

Data Explorer has a query for this already:

https://data.stackexchange.com/apple/s/1421/questions-that-were-migrated-between-sites

I would have been happy to click through a few of these to further qualify my observation, but as it stands I know of no way to view a question simply by entering its ID.

Comment: Can you give us a couple of examples?

Comment: Updated question.

Comment: Obviously, it *should* have been migrated to WebApps...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Apple Stack Exchange is [explicitly not about](https://apple.stackexchange.com/faq) *"Apple Developer Programs or programming"*. Consider it a "consumer" site. The Programmers Stack Exchange [is about "software development" in general](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/faq). For me the distinction with Stack Overflow is whether I'm at the keyboard when I come up with the question.

I think that leaves most iOS development questions on Stack Overflow itself. Looking at [the SO faq](https://stackoverflow.com/faq), you could interpret both *"software tools commonly used by programmers"* and *"matters that are unique to the programming profession"* to be quite wide catch-alls for the examples you gave.

Answer (score 0):

There are questions under tags [development](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/development)  and [developer-program](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/developer-program) which handle non-code questions , App Store rules , policy, etc.

Questions about setting up developer environment are also on-topic.

[beta](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/beta) and [beta-seed-program](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/beta-seed-program) are also relevant.